# PyQt4 get table cell color

Tags: background, pyqt4, python-3.4, qtablewidget

I have what I hope to be a simple question. I would like to have a table, where upon clicking a cell its background gets colored, and upon clicking again - uncolored (back to white). The idea identical to a checkbox, but I don't want a checkbox in my cell (unless it takes up the space of the entire cell and colors itself instead of checking). I'm stuck on how to check the color of a cell's background? If I wanted another cell to get the same color for example, I thought of taking the background color from the colored cell and just use it to another cell. I'm stuck.
I've tried color(), brushStyle() and maybe more (possibly incorrectly). I'm sure it's an easy one for you guys :)

EDIT
Sure, sorry. I mean a QTableWidget, like so:

```
table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
table.setRowCount(3)
table.setColumnCount(3)
```

I would like to get, say, the color of the first cell. I tried using:

```
table.setItem(0, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem())
bg = table.item(0, 0).background().color()

print ("R: " + str(bg.red()) + "; G: " + str(bg.green()) + " ; B: " + str(bg.blue()))
```

I was expecting to get 255 on all RGB values, since I believe the default background to be white. Is the default color white or is there NO color by default? I get all zeros with this code. I just want to be able to make a statement:

```
if (cell is colored)
    set cell background to white (default)
else
    set color to cell background
```

EDIT 2:
Okay so, I managed to create a solution of my own. Posting it here for anybody in need, although I believe the solution to be not great and possibly not working for other uses than mine.

```
def clickTable(row, column):

        if table.item(row, column) == None:
            item1 = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            item1.setBackground(QtGui.QColor(100,100,150))
            table.setItem(row, column ,item1)
        else:
            table.takeItem(row, column)
```

The code responds to:

```
table.cellClicked.connect(clickTable)
```

I'm aware that *takeItem* might make this code useless for most people, but worked for me.

Comment: You will have to be more precise.  What is a "table"? Is it a QTableView? QTableWidget? Do you have a model? Which model? Give us a sample of your code to help us help you.

Answer (score 2):

For changing colors of background and text in individual cells, I've always had to use [`QItemDelegates`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qitemdelegate.html), as the normal methods of palettes and stylesheets don't seem to provide methods to style individual cells.

Essentially, you can define custom data roles (`ItemBackgroundColorRole` in this case) and set data for these custom roles on items in your table widget.  The `QItemDelegate` is responsible for painting your table widget, and we can override the `paint` method to check for these custom data roles and change the colors that the painter uses.

```
class MyDelegate(QItemDelegate):

    ItemBackgroundColorRole = Qt.UserRole + 1

    def __init__(self, parent, table):
        super(MyDelegate, self).__init__(parent)
        self.table = table

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        painter.save()
        item = self.table.itemFromIndex(index)
        if item:
            bg_color = item.data(MyDelegate.ItemBackgroundColorRole)
            if bg_color:
                # These two roles (Window, Base) both style different aspects of the "background"
                # Try with one or both to see which works for you
                option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Window, bg_color)
                option.palette.setColor(QPalette.Base, bg_color)
        super(MyDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)
        painter.restore()


table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
delegate = MyDelegate(None, table)
table.setItemDelegate(delegate)

item = QTableWidgetItem()
item.setData(MyDelegate.ItemBackgroundColorRole, QColor(Qt.red))

# To clear the color and go back to default
item.setData(MyDelegate.ItemBackgroundColorRole, None)
```

To trigger this on cell click, connect to the QTableWidget [`cellClicked`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qtablewidget.html#cellClicked) signal.

```
table.cellClicked.connect(handle_click)

def handle_click(row, column):
    item = table.item(row, column)
    bg_color = item.data(MyDelegate.ItemBackgroundColorRole)
    color = None if bg_color else QColor(Qt.red)
    item.setData(MyDelegate.ItemBackgroundColorRole, color)
```

Comment: I applied your code, adding QtCore and QtGui where it was needed and I'm getting: 'NameError: name 'MyDelegate' is not defined' on the *super(MyDelegate, self).__init__(parent)* line. I might have missed something, though

Comment: Did you name your delegate class MyDelegate?

Comment: I did also fix a typo ( I used tree instead of table)

Comment: I did use MyDelegate. I changed that line to *super().__init__(parent)* and it removed the error - I hope it doesn't break the code? Now I'm getting 'name 'QTableWidgetItem' is not defined' on *item = QTableWidgetItem()* Hope I figure it out

Comment: Just add QtGui before it like the others

Comment: *item = self.table.itemFromIndex(index)* throws "'MyDelegate' object has no attribute 'table'. Sorry for being so braindead :/

Comment: Um.. Did you read my code at all, it sets table in the init of the delegate.  You probably copied it wrong.  This is basic troubleshooting.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Double checked the whole code, now trying to fix "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'" on *bg_color = item.data(MyDelegate.ItemBackgroundColorRole)*

Comment: I apologise, but I'm still stuck. I created a completely blank program with just your code but it still throws a handful of *AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'data'* (I believe one for every cell in the table), both on program startup and on every cell clicked. Either I'm missing an import, a prefix (like QtGui) or used wrong order/indentation

Comment: I'm guessing the error is come from the paint method where it calls item.data() after calling table.itemFromIndex().  The full traceback of the exception should tell you what line it's coming from.  So table.itemFromIndex() is returning None.  Ill update the answer to just ignore that case.  Which would happen if a cell didn't have an item assigned to it.

Comment: But you should be assigning a QTableWidgetItem to every cell.  You can't set data on items if the item doesn't exist in the first place.